# Mocking Classes/ methods in ruby in a functional test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, functional-testing

**Background:-**

I'm currently writing a functional test for a particular controller's action in order to validate its functionality by making a POST request.

**Background on controller's action -**

This action is responsible for creating an application and saving it.

**Controller's action code -**

```
def create_applicaiton

application_data = {
    application_name: request.POST['app_name']
    member_email: request.POST['email']
}

application = ApplicationRecord.new application_data

begin
 StepinHelper.create_issue(application)  //Problem is with this
rescue => error
 Rails.logger.error "Error occurred while creating Issue. Error: #{error}"
 return render plain: "Error occurred while creating Issue. Please try later. Error: #{error}, status: internal_Server_error
end

begin
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
application.save!
end
rescue => error
 Rails.logger.error "Error occurred while creating application. Error: #{error}"
 return render plain: "Error occurred while creating application. Please try later. Error: #{error}, status: internal_Server_error
end
return head :ok
end
```

**The problem is with the line -**

`StepinHelper.create_issue(application)`

where `create_issue` method instantiates a class `IssueCreator` which makes some network calls in order to create the Issue (Think of issue as a notifier that indicates an application is created) which fails during the POST request as its a functional test and the scope is beyond that where it cannot make network calls.

**Here is the code for `create_issue` method present in StepinHelper class -**

```
module StepinHelper
 def self.create_issue application
  issue_title = application.application_name
  issue = IssueCreator.new issue_title //instantiates IssueCreator class
  issue_create = issue.create       //This method creates the issue
  issue_id = issue_create["id"]    //This fetches the "issue_id" from the created issue
  application.add_issue_id issue_id  //This adds issue_id to the schema/table of ApplicationRecord 
 end
end
```

The model of the `ApplicationRecord` has a method - `add_issue_id` as mentioned above which adds a the value of issue_id to its schema's issue_id column.

**This is the model of `ApplicationRecord` -**

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name = "application_record"
......
......

def add_issue_id id
  self.issue_id = id
end
....
....
```

**This is the schema of ApplicationRecord where `issue_id` is set to be ***NOT NULL*****

```
create_table "application_record", id: integer
 t.string "application_name", null: false
 t.string "member_email", null:false
 t.string "issue_id", null:false
end
```

**This is my Functional test code I'm implementing using minitest -**

```
class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

test 'testing_create_applcication' do

StepinHelper.expects(:create_issue).once //mocking

post :create_application, params: {application_name: 'dummyName', member_email: 'dummy@gmail.com'}

assert_response :ok
end
end
```

**Main Problem:-**

Trying to mock `create_issue` method like above. But my assertion fails with a 500 response because as I'm mocking `create_issue` method `issue_id` is not being created and stored in the application records.

**Here is the error response -**

```
Expected response to be a <200:ok> , but was a <500: Internal Server Error>
Response body: Error occurred while creating application. Error: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: application_record.issue_id
Expected: 200
Actual: 500
```

**Expectation/what I'm looking for: -**

1. To make sure issue_id is created by mocking the necessary methods
2. To make my test case pass with a 200 response.

**NOTE**: I shouldn't make changes to the source code.

Comment: I am not entirely clear on what you are asking specifically but one note would be that `ApplicationRecord` is probably a bad choice for a class name. As of Rails 5 this is the base model inheritance.

Comment: @engineersmnky Ultimately I need to mock the following lines in my test and somehow create a ``` issue_id``` to store it in the record.

Lines to be mocked -
issue = IssueCreator.new issue_title 
issue_create = issue.create      
issue_id = issue_create["id"]

Comment: The code in your question has a lot of syntax errors and typos, like missing a dot (between `self issue_id = id`) or missing a colon (in front of the method name in `StepinHelper.expects(create_issue)`), missing commas (between the column name and the options in `t.string "issue_id" null:false`) or naming a method `create_applicaiton`. This makes it almost impossible to guess what problem you might face because of syntax error or other issues. Would we be able to fix those issues or past details about what exceptions or error you observe or are reported in your log file?

Comment: @spickermann Thank you for pointing the mistakes. I've corrected all of them. The issue is I'm unable to perform a mock of IssueCreator class and create a mock 'issue' and generate a mock 'issue_id' in order to save it the application record. 


I've also updated the question with the error I'm observing with the mocking I'm trying to perform.

Comment: What mock/stub gem are you using?
`StepinHelper.expects(:create_issue).once` is not a mock - it's an expectation.  You are not controlling the return object/value.  You probably need to change that to something like `StepinHelper.expects(:create_issue).once { my_mock_object }` and then have the mock object behave the way you want.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.